# Which is faster: raycasting or shadowcasting?

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking to create an FoV implementation and I was wondering which algorithm is faster - raycasting or shadowcasting?

Comment: I'm a game industry veteran. What's a FoV implementation? What is shadowcasting? Never heard of either.

Comment: Do you mean inside a roguelike?

Comment: How about precomputing visibilty with BSP like the good old Quake did? Afterwards you just need to iterate your ray-/shadow-casting over all visible leafs.

Comment: Is it a 2D or 3D world? Is it grid-aligned? Are there many different types of walls?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I'd posted just before an major interruption and was unable to get back to you all right away. @bmcnett, an FoV implementation is a field of view implementation. There's all sorts of information on the web if you Google it. @Tetrad yes. @LumpN how would I go about that? @Sam Hocevar it's a 2D word, grid aligned, one type of wall.

Answer (score 1):

Raycasting and shadow casting are *types* of algorithms, not algorithms themselves (in this context). So neither have any performance characteristics, per se, and thus neither one is faster than the other.

"Shadow casting" as a FOV technique isn't very common, I've only ever seen the term used widely in Roguelike development circles (and in fact the RogueBasin has a number of articles on shadow casting FOV techniques, such as the [spiral path implementation](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php/Spiral_Path_FOV) and plenty of articles on [FOV in general](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php/Field_of_Vision)).

You also might find [this article from GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net/page/reference/index.html/_//feature/fprogramming/walls-and-shadows-in-2d-r2711) interesting.

It's important to remember that there are more factors to consider than just performance -- while shadowcasting techniques tend to be faster than their raycasting counterparts, you pay a trade off in the shape of the results. Some algorithms generate more anomalies and artifacts than others, some procedures don't produce exactly uniform or symmetric results.